# How can I get information about an enemy's elemental weakness? 

Tags: dragon-quest-9

How can I determine elemental weaknesses (the armamentalist abilities can add elemental properties to party members during battle) for enemies? I know thieves have an ability to gain more information on enemies, but it does not appear to display elemental weaknesses (if they exist).

Answer (score 2):

Against most normal monsters, weaknesses rarely come into play as you can beat them down quite fast.  Weaknesses mostly come into play against bosses, and the only place I know of to get weaknesses for bosses is the DQ9 wiki: http://dragonquest.wikia.com/

Comment: It has been awhile since I played, but doesn't the game also notify the player when they hit a weakness by saying its effective or something similar?

Comment: @Xantec - nope, no "super effective" messages here.

Comment: @Katiek - must be another game i am remembering. it gets hard to keep them all straight

Answer (score 1):

The thief's Eye For Trouble ability adds additional information to the Defeated Monster List, which  *sometimes* tells elemental strengths and weaknesses.  If there, it's somewhere in the text description of the monster, and not called out alongside experience or gold per monster.

Answer (score 0):

The best way of telling if an enemy is strong against an element is either to use a Fource, or your common sense! Light will be strong against undead enemies etc.

Answer (score -1):

I just sort of go with what I think would be best. For example, when I have a seasaur I'm battling, I know that fire spells like frizz, or kerfrizz will barely do anything so I go with an attack like dragon slash.

Also sometimes the attack description tells what the attack is good against, such as cattle prod, and others are just plain obvious like metal slash is obviously good against metal monsters, such as a metal slime knight.

Comment: I tried to clarify your post a bit, but the second sentence is still a bit difficult to read. Could you clarify it a little?

Answer (score -1):

If you go [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/937281-dragon-quest-ix-sentinels-of-the-starry-skies/faqs/60450):

It will tell you EVERYTHING about EVERY monster. Computer users can use Ctrl+f to search for words on the page, such as monster names. Use it well. :D

Comment: While this in a sense does answer the question i think the asker was looking to find out the weakness on their own without using a guide. also what happens when the guide is no longer available because the site is down or it's been removed.

Comment: You're right, guess I misinterpreted his question. Thanks.